# How to approach this kind of recursion program

Tags: c, recursion

The answer of simple recursion problem is easy to predict but when it involves multiple calls at a time then it gets difficult (here e(--n) is called two times 
 in single block of scope).
My problem is how to solve this kind of programs by creating TREE kind of structure

```
void e(int);

int main(void)
{
   int a = 3;
   e(a);
   putchar('\n');
   return 0;
}

void e(int n)
{
   if (n > 0)
   {
      e(--n);
      printf("%d ", n);
      e(--n);
   }
}
```

Comment: A pencil and a piece of paper is most appropriate here. Or stepping through the program with your favorite debugger may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it on a piece of paper with a pencil you should get this:

call => e(3);

call => e(2);
call => e(1);
call => e(0);
 initial printf: 0
call => e(-1);
 initial printf: 1
call => e(0);
 initial printf: 2
call => e(1);
call => e(0);
 initial printf: 0
call => e(-1);